# Oracle SQL -- When combining multiple rows with an analytic function, 'prefer' some value over others

Tags: sql, oracle

I might do something like:

```
select 
  max(val), max(val2), max(val3) from table
group by
  val4;
```

Take this sample output:

```
Table
val1   val2   val3   val4
A      P      Z      1
P      Z      P      1
```

For my use case, let's assume that 'P' is an important value, so if a P is showing up somewhere when grouping by val4, that's the value I want to surface. That is, I'd want to surface ('P','P','P') in this case for val1, val2, val3 when grouping by val4.

How can or should this be done?

Comment: Taking the max of a character - not sure that makes sense.  What if 'P' does not exist for a given val?  How do you determine 'next most important?'  Maybe a better example of the input and other possible outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use conditional aggregation.  For instance:

```
select coalesce(max(case when val1 = 'P' then val end), max(val1)) as val1,
       coalesce(max(case when val2 = 'P' then val end), max(val2)) as val2,
       coalesce(max(case when val3 = 'P' then val end), max(val3)) as val3
from table
group by val4;
```

If any of the values match `'P'`, then the first expression in each `coalesce()` returns `'P'`.  If not, the maximum is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ascii` initially to convert the character to ascii value and then use special case for `P` so the value is out of the range. ASCII ranges for A-Z from 65-90.

To get back the character values, use `chr` function.

This solution assumes all the character values are upper case and single characters.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1c70/5)

```
select 
val4,
case when val1 = 100 then 'P' else chr(val1) end val1,
case when val2 = 100 then 'P' else chr(val2) end val2,
case when val3 = 100 then 'P' else chr(val3) end val3
from (
select 
val4,
max(case when val1 = 'P' then 100 else ascii(val1) end) val1,
max(case when val2 = 'P' then 100 else ascii(val2) end) val2,
max(case when val3 = 'P' then 100 else ascii(val3) end) val3 
from t
group by val4) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
RIGHT(MAX(CASE WHEN val1='P' THEN {fn CONCAT(1,val1)} ELSE {fn CONCAT(0,val1)} end),1),
RIGHT(MAX(CASE WHEN val2='P' THEN {fn CONCAT(1,val2)} ELSE {fn CONCAT(0,val2)} end),1),
RIGHT(MAX(CASE WHEN val3='P' THEN {fn CONCAT(1,val3)} ELSE {fn CONCAT(0,val3)} end),1),
val4
Group by val4
```

Intersystems Cache SQL above.. below should work for other flavors?

```
select
RIGHT(MAX(CASE WHEN val1='P' THEN CONCAT(1,val1) ELSE CONCAT(0,val1) end),1),
RIGHT(MAX(CASE WHEN val2='P' THEN CONCAT(1,val2) ELSE CONCAT(0,val2) end),1),
RIGHT(MAX(CASE WHEN val3='P' THEN CONCAT(1,val3) ELSE CONCAT(0,val3) end),1),
val4
Group by val4
```